# Could the Fourier transform of a one-sided non-negative function be compactly supported?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I know the Fourier transform of a compactly supported function cannot be compacted supported. But what if the function is supported on $(0,+\infty)$ or $(-\infty,0)$? Is there any chance for its Fourier transform be compactly supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inverse Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function of compact support is an entire function.  Therefore it can't be zero on any set with a finite limit point, in particular $(0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question! Just wonder why the entire function cannot be zero on any set with a finite limit point?

Comment: [Identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem): an analytic function on a connected open set $D$ that is $0$ on a set with a limit point in $D$ is identically $0$.